# Custom variable in custom block template

Tags: 8

I'm trying to create a block that will pass a variable to its template. For now just some text but it will be an array later.

The default block variables such as label are working but I'm unable to get the value to show up in template.

Any ideas ?

*FrontAppsBlock.php*

```
namespace Drupal\custom_blocks\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockPluginInterface;
/**
 * @Block(
 *   id = "front_apps_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Front Apps Block"),
 * )
 */
class FrontAppsBlock extends BlockBase implements BlockPluginInterface {

  public function build() {
    return array(
      '#theme' => 'front_apps_block',
      '#app' => 'test value',
    );
  }

}
```

*custom_blocks.module*

```
function custom_blocks_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'front_apps_block' => [
      'variables' => [
        'app' => null
      ]
    ]
  ];
}
```

*block--front-apps-block.html.twig*

```
<p>test: {{ app }}</p>
<p>label: {{ label }}</p>
```

Comment: Your twig variable name is test, but defined as app. Did you try outputting `{{ app }}` ?

Comment: Can you tell me what's the name of you template ? And like Kevin said, you should print {{ app }} in your twig template.

Comment: My bad, I changed the name last second, I have `{{ app }}` in my template. And it is not displaying anything.

Comment: Did you create the `content()` function for your block? see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/create-custom-twig-templates-from-custom-module

Comment: I think for custom blocks the `content()` function is not needed since it uses the `build()` function.

Comment: Please any help here? :(
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/260599/passing-variables-to-block-drupal-8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After long hours of searching and trying I finally found a solution.
Not really sure why but it seems a naming convention has to be respected.

I changed the name of #theme and templates to **start with module name**, here the name is **custom_blocks**.

*src/Plugin/Block/FrontAppsBlock.php*

```
/**
 * @Block(
 *   id = "front_apps_block",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Front Apps Block"),
 * )
 */
class FrontAppsBlock extends BlockBase implements BlockPluginInterface {

  public function build() {
    return [
      '#theme' => 'custom_blocks__front_apps',
      '#app' => 'test value',
    ];
  }

}
```

*custom_blocks.module*

```
function custom_blocks_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'custom_blocks__front_apps' => [
      'variables' => [
        'app' => null
      ],
    ]
  ];
}
```

*templates/custom-blocks--front-apps.html.twig*

```
<p>Hello: {{ app }}</p>
<p>Base Label: {{ label }}</p>
```