# Pass PHP variables from my custom block to my custom Twig template

Tags: 8, theming, blocks

I created a custom block module `my_block`. Inside `modules/custom/my_block/src/Plugin/Block/MyBlock.php` I have this code:

```
<?php
    namespace Drupal\my_block\Plugin\Block;
    use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
    /**
     * Provides'My Block' Block.
     *
     * @Block(
     *  id = "my_block",
     *  admin_label = @Translation("MyBlock block"),
     *  category = @Translation("Our Example block"),
     * )
     */

    class MyBlock extends BlockBase {

      /**
       * {@inheritdoc}
       */
       public function build() {
         $build = [];

         for ($day = 1; $day <= 100; $day++) {
           if ($day % 15 == 0) {
               echo $foo . $bar <br>;
           } elseif ($day % 3 == 0) {
               echo $foo '<br>';
           } elseif ($day % 5 == 0) {
               echo $bar . '<br>';
           } else {
               echo $day . '<br>';
           }
         }

     $block = [
       '#theme' => 'my_template',
       '#cache' => [
         'max-age' => strtotime('01/01/'.(date('Y')+1)) - time(),
       ],
     ];

     $build = $block;

     return $build;
  }

}
```

I also created a template file `modules/custom/my_block/templates/my-template.html.twig` and attached it to my custom module.

I have another file `modules/custom/my_block/my_block.module`:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
 function fizzbuzz_block_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
   return [
     'my_template' => [
       //'variables' => ['markup' => NULL, 'test_var' => NULL],
       'variables' => [
         'test_var' => '',
       ],
     ],
   ];
 }
```

How do I output the values from the *if/else condition*s from `modules/custom/my_block/src/Plugin/Block/MyBlock.php`, into my custom block and so I am able to render them in my twig file `modules/custom/my_block/templates/my-template.html.twig`. E.g.

#### Show: {{ result }}

Do I somehow have to parse some variables inside the `public function build()` function?

Comment: I guess we need to so see more of your code to help you.

Comment: You need to define variables in a theme hook and then pass them in MyBlock.php, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/246119/8-custom-variable-in-custom-block

Comment: @leymannx I insert some code in my question and made it more clear. Thanks!

Comment: Now the question is less clear. It's not clear where you are using the first snippet code you show, but blocks don't use `echo`. That is not the way to output a block content.